# Is this an abuse of OOP and Java?

Tags: java, oop

Let's say you have this class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array
{
  private ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();

  public void add(Object element)
  {
    a.add(element);
  }

  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
      a.add(elements[i]); // this line is going to be changed
  }
}
```

And this derived class:

```
public class ArrayCount extends Array
{
  private int count = 0;

  @Override
  public void add(Object element)
  {
    super.add(element);
    ++count;
  }

  @Override
  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    super.addAll(elements);
    count += elements.length;
  }
}
```

If in the base class, we make the following change:

```
  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
      add(elements[i]); // this line was changed
  }
```

I would expect the add() method in the base class to be called, not the overridden add() in the derived class. Why is this not the case? And is this example an abuse of OOP?

Comment: Abuse?  That is polymorphism.

Comment: That would be polymorphism, not abuse :)

Comment: If you want to explicitly call a method from the base class, use `super.add(element)`

Comment: Although `Array` is a terrible name for a user class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

Comment: @Philipp the issue about calling `super.add(element)` is that the method that was changed was in the parent class. Therefore, there might not be a `super.add(element)` to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java will always call the method implementation of the runtime class (the real object class at runtime), as long as it's a valid method override. That's called dynamic binding.

You are not abusing, but exploiting a guaranteed feature.

What you have as design is legal in Java, but is a bad practice for many reasons, of which you highlighted an important one. This is one of the primary reasons why implementation inheritance is sometimes discouraged, in favor of interface inheritance.

Comment: related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315344/is-overriding-concrete-methods-a-code-smell

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, it boils down to what happens at runtime.

Since the function is `add()`, it'll invoke the `add()` for `this` object which is the overridden function during runtime.

This is the whole point of encapsulation, a child class should have total control over what its methods do.

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect the add() method in the base class to be called, not the overridden add() in the derived class. Why is this not the case?

Java uses dynamic dispatch, also known as dynamic binding, to bind methods at runtime. In simple terms, this means that when a method is called on a base class, the method that's executed is that of the actual type of the object. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) or the [Java reference on polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

> Is this example an abuse of OOP?

For a contrived example that demonstrates dynamic dispatch, it's not bad. For anything else, it's pointless.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following change fixes the problem:

> If in the base class, we make the following change:

```
  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
      super.add(elements[i]);     // <-- new use of SUPER
  }
```

Basically, if you want certain methods to be invariant (always do the same thing) you have to declare them `final` to prevent overriding.  Otherwise, a derived class can implement anything they want.

(The fix to *that* is to write documentation explaining what the contract is that any derived method must follow.)